# count function in python list

Tags: python, compiler-errors

**Hello comrades, I want to take a character from the input and convert it to a list, and then show the number of repetitions of each index to the user, but it gives an error.**

> my code:

```
list = list(input("plase enter keyword"))

for item in list:
    print(f"value({item})"+list.count(item))
```

> my error

```
TypeError 
Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\emanull\Desktop\test py\main.py in <cell line: 3>()
      2 list = list(input("plase enter keyword"))
      4 for item in list:
----> 5     print(f"value({item})"+list.count(item))

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: `print(f"value({item}) {list.count(item)}")` and it's probably a good idea to not use the keyword `list` as a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
list_ = list(input("plase enter keyword"))

for item in list_:
    print(f"value({item}) {list_.count(item)}")
```

OR

```py
list_ = list(input("plase enter keyword"))

for item in list_:
    print(f"value({item})"+str(list_.count(item)))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very good at English

Answer (score 0):

Firstly overshadowing `list` built-in is bad idea, secondly you need to convert number into `str` if you want to concatenate it with other `str`, after applying these changes

```
lst = list(input("plase enter keyword"))

for item in lst:
    print(f"value({item})"+str(lst.count(item)))
```

but be warned that it will print more than once for repeated item

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the error is that you are trying to concatenate a string and a integer which is not possible in python unlike javascript.So try to convert your integer to a string using str keyword and then concatenate.